# Toggle automatically through images which lie upon each other

Tags: jquery, image, toggle

There are five images which lie upon each other and I would like to toggle automatically (each second) between all of them. Any idea how to handle that?

https://dstruning.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using window.setInterval and jQuery as following:

```
let currentImage = 0;

// Set interval will call the function every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
window.setInterval(function(){
  // Let's select which image we want to show.
  currentImage += 1;
  // Hide all images
  $('img').hide();
  // Show only image you want to show currently. 
  // We're using %5 to always get numbers between 0 and 4
  $('img:nth(' + (currentImage % 5) + ')').show();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you for the code! i would like to have the images lying above each other instead of showing only one per time (like a constant carousel). any idea?

Comment: Then you'll have to use CSS for it. Set z-index to each image and instead of using jQuery to show/hide images use it to set z-index css property: $('img').css({'zIndex': 4})

Comment: i set z-index to all images, but how do you mean "use it to set z-index css property"?

Comment: remove $('img').hide(); and replace $('img:nth(' + (currentImage % 5) + ')').show(); with $('img:nth(' + (currentImage % 5) + ')').css({zIndex: currentImage});

Comment: great, it works - but there seems to be a delay at the beginning? see at https://dstruning.com/

Comment: It seems fine to me. Maybe the delay is due to images getting loaded first. Try to lower the size of images.